# Consistent domain/type aliasing behaviour in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a tool for building type-safe wrappers around PostgreSQL, and would like to use domains to play with the postgres type system. Example:

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN userid AS int8;
CREATE TABLE users (
  id userid NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO users VALUES 37;
```

The problem appears when I try to run any kind of SELECT query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users \gdesc
```

the above returns:

```
 Column |  Type   
--------+---------
 id     | integer
```

The domain type is completely thrown out! Even the following:

```sql
SELECT id::userid FROM users \gdesc
SELECT CAST(id as userid) FROM users \gdesc
```

both return the same type signature. My new feature relies on having aliases for existing types so that it can enforce its own arbitrary rules upon them, but I'm not sure how that can work when domain information is being totally clobbered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domains won't do for that.

You'd have to create your own data types using `CREATE TYPE`. You will be able to reuse many of the existing C functions, but you may have to write some C functions yourself.

The question is whether that is worth the effort for a thin layer that may add a lot of confusion for existing tools and people who know PostgreSQL.